# csvreader has integer overflow at 16384 = 2**14

Tags: csvsimple

I have to send quite a bit of documentation to Germany for taxes. I created some TeX files which use some CSV files to automatically generate this report. So far, I was a student and numbers were low. Last year I started working and I just noticed that my earnings last year cause `csvsimple` to fail. How do I fix it?

### Minimal Example

`2017-nicht-selbststaendig.csv`:

```
Datum;Text;Betrag
18.12.2017;Lohnsteuer Empoyer 2017;16384.00
```

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % needed for right umlaut output in pdf
\usepackage[ngerman, num]{isodate} % get DD.MM.YYYY dates
\usepackage[locale=DE,group-minimum-digits={3}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[rmargin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\fancypagestyle{appendix}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % fixes \headheight warning
\lhead{Martin Thoma, Poststraße 1, 81234 München}
\rhead{Id-Nr. 72 123 123}

% Begin document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section*{Überschussrechnung 2017}

\subsection*{Einnahmen aus nicht-selbstständiger Tätigkeit}
\csvreader[before reading=\def\nichstselbststaendig{0},separator=semicolon]{2017-nicht-selbststaendig.csv}{Betrag=\Betrag}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nichstselbststaendig}{\nichstselbststaendig+\Betrag}%
}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10.4cm}|p{2cm}|}\hline%
\textbf{Datum} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Betrag}
\csvreader[head to column names,separator=semicolon]{2017-nicht-selbststaendig.csv}{}%
{\\\hline\Datum & \Text &\hfill\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\Betrag}}%
\\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Summe} & \hfill\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\nichstselbststaendig}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

### The error

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.30 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not csvsimple but pgfmath. If you use xfp and `\fpeval` to do the sum, it works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % needed for right umlaut output in pdf
\usepackage[ngerman, num]{isodate} % get DD.MM.YYYY dates
\usepackage[locale=DE,group-minimum-digits={3}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[rmargin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple,xfp}

\fancypagestyle{appendix}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % fixes \headheight warning
\lhead{Martin Thoma, Poststraße 1, 81234 München}
\rhead{Id-Nr. 72 123 123}

% Begin document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\section*{Überschussrechnung 2017}

\subsection*{Einnahmen aus nicht-selbstständiger Tätigkeit}
\csvreader[before reading=\def\nichstselbststaendig{0},separator=semicolon]{testcsv.csv}{Betrag=\Betrag}{%
\edef\nichstselbststaendig{\fpeval{\nichstselbststaendig+\Betrag}}%
}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10.4cm}|p{2cm}|}\hline%
\textbf{Datum} & \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Betrag}
\csvreader[head to column names,separator=semicolon]{testcsv.csv}{}%
{\\\hline\Datum & \Text &\hfill\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\Betrag}}%
\\\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Summe} & \hfill\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\nichstselbststaendig}
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```